# How can i get path of the installed program from the registry in nsis?

Tags: nsis

How can i get path of the installed program from the registry in nsis?
i am reading registry by readregistry command and assigned to a variable.actually i want to locate my uninstall.exe location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [`InstallDirRegKey`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.1.22) instruction, you can specify a registry key where the `$INSTDIR` directory will be saved for future usage. That key is automatically read the next time the installer starts.

You can use that to locate the `uninstall.exe`

You can also write several keys when installing to configure the windows "add / remove programs", then the unistaller can be located by the `UninstallString` registry value:

```
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\my_application"
WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"  "DisplayName" "my_application Uninstaller"
WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"  "DisplayIcon" "$INSTDIR\my_application.exe,0"
WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"  "Publisher" "My company"
WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"  "HelpTelephone" "555-123456"

WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "UninstallString" '"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"'
```